# SQL Server TOP clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some difficult with this clause.

How can I select rows with an interval? I mean like clause limit in MySQL

For example we have this table called "`TB`":

```
 id | brand
----|-----
  1 | samsung
  2 | hp
  3 | microsoft
  4 | apple
  5 | sony
  6 | acer
  7 | google
  8 | facebook
```

I want to select the rows between 3 and 6. In MySQL there is a clause limit wish do that:

```
select * from TB limit 2,3
```

The question is how can I do it with clause `TOP`?

I want to use this clause in a page asp.net wish it display all products by receiving a parameter of page.

How can I do it with SQL Server `top` clause ?

Comment: Which version you are using? 2008 or 2012?

Comment: If you want to have records between 3 and 6 then why TOP clause? can't you achieve this with BETWEEN? Please share sample output.

Comment: i use the 2012, why ur asking ?

Comment: i dont want to use  it cause it not static ! i dont want to specified by ID column but by ROW !

Comment: So on which basis you want to apply sort  for TOP? Please share sample output.

Comment: im not sure if TOP clause is the right choice, i just want a clause wish display rows by an interval like LIMIT in mysql cause the TOP clause display  all from the beginning until the number specified and i want to select on an interval wich is dynamic (wish it gonna be the parametere of page in page aspx who show product by pages)

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using SQL Server 2012, I think you require "Offset & Fetch Next"
Please try following

```
Declare @startFrom int = 5 ---- From which row you want to start
Declare @recCount int = 2  ----- No of records you want to Fetch

select * from myTable
order by id
offset @startFrom rows
fetch next @recCount rows only
```

SQL Fiddle **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/366dc/6)**